# phonegap iOS file.path

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a app using cordova 3.4 and file 1.1.0.
If I copy a image using the camera-modul, I use

```
myFileObj.path = file.toNativeURL()
```

to get the file-path. If I put this path into a img-tag I get shown the picture on Android.
On iOS it doesn't work. The result of file.toNativeURL():

```
myFileObj.path -> file:///Users/.../Library/Application%20Support/..../myFolder/myImage.JPG
```

Using file 1.0 I had to build the url and it looked like this:

```
myFileObj.path = dirTarget.toURL() + '/' + targetFileName 
myFileObj.path -> cdvfile://localhost/persisten/myFolder/myImage.JPG
```

Where videos and audios didn't work, but at least pictures.

Using file 1.1.0/1.1.1 the result of this method is different too:

```
myFileObj.path -> file:///Users/mak/Library/.../myFolder/myImage.JPG?id=.....&ext=JPG
```

This doesn't work on iOS either.

How can I get a working file-path by using cordova file-module version 1.1.0 and 1.1.1?

EDIT: What am I doing and what doesn't work:

I copy images from the media-library and put it into a folder I create myself.
What works in Android and doesn't work in iOS:
In Android the media-tags src attribute is able to display the resource, iOS can't find a resource at the src-path.

catching a file from the media-library:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
  });
```

success-callback:

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
    A.StoreFile(imageData, id);
}
```

create a folder and store file:

```
A.StoreFile = function(file, idBox) {

    var targetDirectory = Config.getRootPath();
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file, resolveFileSystemSuccess, resolveFileSystemError);


    function resolveFileSystemSuccess(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(filee) {
        mimeType = filee.type;
        getFileSuccess(fileEntry, mimeType);
    }, function() {
    });
}


function getFileSuccess(fileEntry, mimeType) {

    var targetFileName = name + '.' + fileNativeType;

    var parentName = targetDirectory.substring(targetDirectory.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
    parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(parentName, targetDirectory);


    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(targetDirectory, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dirTarget) {
            fileEntry.copyTo(dirTarget, targetFileName, function(entry) {
                addFileToLocalStorage(entry);
            }, function() {
            })
        })
    }, resolveFileSystemError);

}
```

store file-information to a localStorageObject

```
function addFileToLocalStorage(file) {
    fileList.addFile(
        {
            name:file.name,
            internalURL: file.toNativeURL()
        });
}
```

adding files dynamically to the dom:

```
myElement.find('.myMimeTypeTag').attr('src', fileList[f].internalURL);
```

This works with android, and not with iOS.

iOS-result of img-container:

[image]

Error-message:

```
DEPRECATED: Update your code to use 'toURL'
```

toURL doesn't work either

```
id="org.apache.cordova.file"
version="1.1.1-dev"
```

Comment: Please define exactly how your app isn't working -- error messages, etc. Also provide all your code for the operation (so also the code that is performing the copy).

Comment: See the edit-section of my post please.

Comment: I've successfully used `.toURL()` on both Android and iOS7, but it was with Cordova 3.2.0 and File 0.2.5.  With those versions, `.toURL()` returns URLs in the form: `file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/05335E1C-B7BC-458C-8050-2C9C4F1CB969/Documents/test.png` Maybe you can compare your result of `.toURL()` in 1.1.0 with this?

Comment: using 1.1.0 .toURL() delivers file:///Users/mak/Library/.../myFolder/myImage.JPG?id=.....&ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the new file-plugin has to be case-sensitve.
I created a folder with capital letters and refered the copy-instruction to a folder with lowercase letters. The point is that android is case insensitive and ios is not.
This came out with the new file-plugin where the output was case sensitive.

Comment: Are you saying that the output of one of the File plugin methods is incorrectly cased? Or was this an error in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this out, with a slightly simplified version of your code (you seem to have a lot of extra structure to your code that isn't shown, but if there's a significant difference between what I've done here and what your app does, then let me know. The problem will be in the difference.)

I've run this with Cordova 3.5.0, just released, using File 1.1.0 and Camera 0.2.9.

To create the app, I used the `cordova` command line tool, and just ran

```
cordova create so23801369 com.example.so23801369 so23801369
cd so23801369
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

This creates a default "Hello, Cordova" app, to which I've added some code that (I believe) replicates what your code does.

I added two lines to index.html:

```
<button id="doit">Do it</button>
<img class="myMimeTypeTag" src="file:///nothing" />
```

And I edited `www/js/index.js` to look like this:

```
var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        // Don't activate the button until Cordova is initialized
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        document.getElementById('doit').addEventListener('click', app.runTest, false);
    },

    runTest: function(ev) {
        var StoreFile = function(file) {
            var targetDirectory = "myFolder";
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file, resolveFileSystemSuccess, resolveFileSystemError);

            function resolveFileSystemSuccess(fileEntry) {
                console.log("resolveLocalFileSystemURL returned: ", fileEntry.toURL());
                fileEntry.file(function(filee) {
                    mimeType = filee.type;
                    getFileSuccess(fileEntry, mimeType);
                }, function() {
                });
            }
            function resolveFileSystemError() {
                console.log("resolveFileSystemError: FAIL");
                console.log(arguments);
                alert("FAIL");
            }

            function getFileSuccess(fileEntry, mimeType) {
                var targetFileName = "myImage.JPG";
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(targetDirectory, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dirTarget) {
                        fileEntry.copyTo(dirTarget, targetFileName, function(entry) {
                            console.log("copyTo returned: ", entry.toURL());
                            // I have replaced the localstorage handling with this code
                            // addFileToLocalStorage(entry);
                            var img = document.querySelector('.myMimeTypeTag');
                            img.setAttribute('src', entry.toNativeURL());
                        }, function() {
                        });
                    });
                }, resolveFileSystemError);
            }
        };

        var onSuccess = function(imageData) {
            console.log("getPicture returned: ", imageData);
            StoreFile(imageData);
        };

        var onFail = function() {
            console.log("getPicture FAIL");
            console.log(arguments);
            alert("FAIL");
        };

        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
        });
    }
};
```

When I run this, I can pick an image from the media library, and it successfully displays it in the page, with the image src set to the URL of the copied image file. If I connect Safari dev tools to the iPad, I see this console output:

```
[Log] getPicture returned:  assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=F9B8C942-367E-433A-9A71-40C5F2806A74&ext=JPG (index.js, line 49)
[Log] resolveLocalFileSystemURL returned:  cdvfile://localhost/assets-library/asset/asset.JPG?id=F9B8C942-367E-433A-9A71-40C5F2806A74&ext=JPG (index.js, line 18)
[Log] copyTo returned:  file:///var/mobile/Applications/9C838867-30BE-4703-945F-C9DD48AB4D64/Documents/myFolder/myImage.JPG (index.js, line 36)
[Log] DEPRECATED: Update your code to use 'toURL' (Entry.js, line 202)
```

This shows the camera and file plugins going through three different types of URL:

- Camera returns an `assets-library://` URL, with query parameters to identify the asset
- calling resolveLocalFileSystemURL on that turns it into a `cdvfile://` URL, also with query paramaters, as an internal Cordova representation.
- After being copied, File returns a new `file:///` URL showing the image's new place on the filesystem. This URL has no query parameters. (Calling toNativeURL() on this entry returns the same URL now, as of File 1.1.0)

This final URL is usable by iOS as an image source, and so that's what gets assigned to the `<img>` element.

Comment: I created a new project and applied your implemantation. It worked as it should. I don't see any differences to what I was doing. I asked a colleague to take a look at the entire project. I'll let you know if it works or not then. Thanks a lot for your answer, you also can pm me by e-mail.

Comment: I found out what went wrong. I couldn't reveal the original code, where I had a reference mistake. The new plugin updates output has to be case sensitive. file-plugin <1.0 doesn't have to.